# Is there a such thing as "Stacked Vector Notation"?

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, normal-distribution, matrix-equations

I was reading this link over here: https://peterroelants.github.io/posts/gaussian-process-tutorial/ . I came across the following statements:

[image]

**I am trying to understand how to "fill in the entries" of the vector [mu_1,mu_2].**

Based on the context, we can see that "mu_1" and "mu_2" are not scalars - we can see that "mu_1" and "mu_2" are both vectors themselves.

Suppose I have the following data:

- **Fully Known:** (x1,y1), (x2, y2) .... (xn,yn)
- **Partially Known:** (x_n+1), (x_n+2) .... (x_n+m)

In this case, I am interested in knowing how to "fill in the entries" of the [mu_1, mu_2] vector. In theory, would the [mu_1, mu_2] vector look like : [**mu_1, mu_2] = [m(x1), m(x2) .... m(xn), m(x_n+1), m(x_n+2) ....m(x_n+m)]** ?

**My Question:** In the case of the [mu_1, mu_2] vector, can we simply "stack" all these elements on top of each other? Is there such a thing as a "stacked vector notation" in mathematics?

Thanks!

**Note:** I think in the real world, when we are trying to find the joint probability distribution of [y1, y2] - I am not sure how to calculate **m(X2)** . In Gaussian Processes, I am told that mu_1 = m(X1) = m(Y1) . I do not know how we could calculate mu_2 = m(X2) = m(Y2) since Y2 is unknown in real world applications.

Comment: The notation you are using is clear enough. Never heard of stacked vector notation but why not call it that way ?

Comment: @Kurt G. Notation "Vec" for "columns stacking" operation on a matrix becomes classical ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics). It is very useful in particular in the context of computations with Kronecker product.

Comment: Why should this well formulated question be closed ?

Comment: @JeanMarie . I am totally fine when nobody else votes to close and thanks for the comment . However pure notation such as $\operatorname{Vec}(a,b)$ never tells me anything. There are very cheap ways to avoid ambiguities, and OP already has one.